# Trying to copy a table to csv file and name it using original file name

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and stuck on an issue. I'm trying to copy a table to a .csv file and I want the end result to contain the original .xlsm name & the table name and date/time. I've successfully pieced together code to export the table to .csv with the table name and date/time but I'm struggling to get the file mane in there. I get the following error "Method 'SaveAs' of object'_Workbook' failed" 
Below is what I have, any help would be great!

```
Sub ExportTableBanquetEarnings()
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 Sheets("BanquetEarnings").Visible = True
 Sheets("BanquetEarnings").Select

Dim wb As Workbook, wbNew As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
Dim wbNewName As String
Dim wbCurrent As String

wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = ActiveSheet

Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add


With wbNew
   Set wsNew = wbNew.Sheets("Sheet1")
   wbNewName = ws.ListObjects(1).Name
   ws.ListObjects(1).Range.Copy
   wsNew.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll
   .SaveAs Filename:="F:\admin\Report Databases\BanquetTipouts" & "\" & 
    wbCurrent & wbNewName & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmm") & ".csv", _
         FileFormat:=xlCSVMSDOS, CreateBackup:=False
 End With

 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ActiveWorkbook.Close
 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 Sheets("BanquetEarnings").Visible = False
 Sheets("Blank Cost Sheet").Select
 Workbooks.Open "F:\Function Agreements\Cost Sheets M\Payroll Report - 
   V2.xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the wbCurrent statement.

Answer (score 0):

The below code will show the path of that Workbook

```
wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

I think what you meant to use is...

```
wbCurrent = ThisWorkbook.Name
```

Also, I think another issue might be the Now method, it should be as `Now()`

Comment: No problem, if this was able to answer your question please mark it as answered so anyone else looking for the similar solution to their issue can easily find it